# IEEE 754 Floating Point Round to Nearest

Tags: floating-point, rounding, ieee-754

In my notes I have something like

```
If (Guard & !Round & !Sticky)
    If (LSB == 1) 
        LSB += 1
Else If (Guard) 
    LSB += 1
End If
```

So I could just simplify it to

```
If Guard Then 
    LSB += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. What about this case?

```
Guard==true
Sticky==false
Round==false
LSB==0
```

The original code would *not* execute `LSB += 1` in that case, yours would.

Comment: Err ... wait is my 1st block of code wrong? If `Guard & Sticky & !LSB`, It will execute `LSB += 1` from the Else? Or maybe you meant `Guard & !Sticky & !LSB`?